# Images flicker when creating a fade between two images in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a `<Background>` component that is capable of creating a fade between two images. On the first time it is rendered, the image should fade from transparent to full opacity; on subsequent renders, the previous image should be kept and used as the starting point for the fade, so you'll see the new image fading in on top of the previous one.

So my logic is:

- On `componentWillReceiveProps` I save the current props to `this.state.previousBackground` before they get lost;
- When it's time to render, I check for the existence of a previous background. If there isn't one (first render), I just render the new background. If there is one, I render the previous background first (at full opacity) and the new background right after, animating its opacity from `0` to `1`.

It does what it's supposed to, but the images flicker on every transition. It's like I can see the new background in full opacity for a split second before it disappears and starts fading in.

If anyone has any idea of what might be causing this, it'd be much appreciated. I'm attaching the code for my component, please let me know if any of it isn't clear.

I'm using RN 0.21.

Many thanks!

EDIT: I've also tried not using `position: absolute`, but keep the previous background relatively positioned and move the new background on top of it by using a `translateY`. The result is the same.

```
'use strict';

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// React components
// --------------------------------------------------------------

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  View
} = React;

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Application components
// --------------------------------------------------------------

var Animations = require('./Animations');
var BaseStyle = require('../utils/BaseStyle');
var Constants = require('../constants/AppConstants');
var EpisodeActions = require('../actions/EpisodeActions');
var Video = require('react-native-video').default;

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Component declaration
// --------------------------------------------------------------

var Background = React.createClass({
  _animate: function () {
    Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
      toValue: this.props.opacity,
      duration: fadeDuration
    }).start(EpisodeActions.backgroundFinishedAnimating);
  },

  _renderBackground: function (background, isPreviousBackground) {
    if (!background) {
      return null;
    }

    var imageStyle = {};

    if (!isPreviousBackground) {
      imageStyle.opacity = this.state.opacity;
    }

    return (
      <Animated.Image
        //resizeMode="cover"
        source={{uri: background.src}}
        style={[styles.fullScreen, imageStyle]}
      />
    );
  },

  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
      backdropColor: '#000',
      opacity: 1
    };
  },

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      opacity: new Animated.Value(0),
      previousBackground: null
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    //this._animate();
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function (newProps) {
    var newState = {
      opacity: new Animated.Value(0)
    };

    if (newProps.data.src !== this.props.data.src) {
      newState.previousBackground = this.props.data;
    }

    this.setState(newState);
  },

  shouldComponentUpdate: function (newProps, newState) {  
    if (this.props.data.src === newProps.data.src) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function (oldProps, oldState) {
    //this._animate();
  },  

  render: function () {
    this._animate();

    return (
      <View style={[styles.fullScreen, {backgroundColor: this.props.backdropColor}]}>
        {this._renderBackground(this.state.previousBackground, true)}
        {this._renderBackground(this.props.data)}
      </View>
    );
  }
});

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Styling
// --------------------------------------------------------------

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fullScreen: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});

module.exports = Background;
```

Comment: Does it help if you put a `key` on them? You might consider extracting `_renderBackground` to its own (non-exported) e.g. `Layer` component, and modifying `Background.render` to return `<View ...> <Layer key="prev" ... /> <Layer key="next" ... /> </View>`. Try to meet the view-diffing algorithm halfway? Just a thought.

Comment: @Tom not really. (regarding `key`; will try the code you posted on your edit)

Comment: Interestingly, if I add a `delay` of `1000` to the animation, I can see the image for longer (1s) before it disappears and starts fading in, which leads me to believe that `Animated` is introducing a tiny delay that's causing the flickering.

Comment: ^ Ideally I'd be able to guarantee that the opacity is `0` until `Animated` kicks in and starts bringing it up to `1`.

Comment: @Tom separating it out into a different component didn't help either :/ I really think the issue is with `Animated` having a small delay, but I don't see any way of guaranteeing that the opacity will be `0` until `Animated` kicks in.